# haproxy timing connection diagram

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to understand more about the Haproxy timings.  Below is a snippet of the timings from the Haproxy manual:

> - Tq: total time to get the client request (HTTP mode only)...
> - Tw: total time spent in the queues waiting for a connection slot...
> - Tc: total time to establish the TCP connection to the server....
> - Tr: server response time (HTTP mode only)...
> - Tt: total session duration time, between the moment the proxy accepted it
>     and the moment both ends were closed...

***Source:*** http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#8.4

I've attempted to diagram some of the timings, but **my diagram is probably incorrect** and **is definitely incomplete** (no FIN, etc):

[image]

**Question:** What would the full timing diagram look like, including all timing measures (Tq, Tw, Tc, Tr, Tt) as well as all TCP/IP communications?

Comment: I think Tr starts after Tc finishes.  Does haproxy wait for the full request before starting a backend connection?  Tw might start earlier.

Comment: Thanks for making this diagram.  What did you draw it in?

Comment: @chicks - I used [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/)

Comment: @chicks - please assume my diagram is incorrect :) - I only added the diagram to show how I am thinking about the timings.

Comment: I was trying to make useful suggestions, not presuming anything.  It is cool that you used dia for this.  I like dia for my database diagrams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice picture :)

- timeout connect is on server side, it is the maximum time to run the TCP handshake
- http-request starts from the ACK on the client side until whole HTTP headers have been received
- Tq starts from the client Handshake TCP.
- Tr is until we receive the response Headers

Baptiste

Comment: thanks for the info, however, I was hoping for a complete timing diagram including all measures, and also showing all the TCP session setup and tear down.  Are you part of the Haproxy development team?

Comment: on a HTTPS session, the Tq timer starts after the TCP handshake finishes and before the SSL handshake starts?

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of the HAProxy Configuration Manual include a diagram of the timer sequence: [8.4 Timing Events](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.4)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [official](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) docs, [Here](https://github.com/hojat-gazestani/DevOps/blob/main/haproxy/01-Conepts/01-Protocols.md) I created a brief and precise answer.

[image]

```
Tq:
    - total time to get the client request from the accept date (Th + Ti + TR)
    TH: total time to accept tcp connection and execute handshakes
    Ti: is the idle time before the HTTP request
    TR: total time to get the client request
    
Tw: the time needed for the server to complete previous requests
Tc: between the moment the proxy sent the connection request, and the moment it was acknowledged by the server
Tr: between the moment the TCP connection was established to the server and the moment the server sent its complete response headers.
```